# How would I write this ternary operation as a conditional statement?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

Hi I would like to know how to write the following ternary operation as a regular conditional statement. If someone could let me know that would be greatly appreciated, here is the code:

```
h1.textContent = "Time : " + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);
```

Comment: you'd need two if statements, one for each

Comment: by the way ... I'd do `('0' + minutes).substr(-2)` and be done with ternary or conditional statements :p

Comment: could you show me how that would look in practise, I'm new to javascript and would like to understand more about ternary operations

Comment: but ... you're using ternary operator ... you need to know about "conditional statements" don't you? `if (condition) { code to run when condition is true } else { code to run when condition is false }`

Comment: Yeah I understand basic javascript fine, I'm just trying to learn how to construct a ternary operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd go something like this:

```
var text = "Time : ";
if (minutes){
    if (minutes > 9){
        text += minutes;
    }
    else{
        text += "0" + minutes;
    }
}
else{
    text += "00";
}
text += ":";
if (seconds > 9){
    text += seconds;
}
else{
    text += "0" + seconds;
}
h1.textContent = text;
```

Personally, I'd rather stick with the ternary [image]

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot! I was just trying to understand more about the ternary operations and how they work etc.

Comment: They're simple. A ternary is basically an expression that returns a result based on a conditional. You have three key components (hence the name ternary): a boolean, a value to return if the boolean is true, and a boolean to return if the boolean is false. Like this: `isTrue ? 'yes' : 'no'`

Answer (score 1):

A simple "conditional statements" alternative

```
var minutesS = minutes;
if (minutes < 10) minutesS = '0' + minutes;

var secondsS = seconds;
if (seconds < 10) seconddS = '0' + seconds;

h1.textContent = "Time : " + minutesS + ":" + secondsS;
```

Comment: This is much cleaner :D

Comment: but your code demonstrates what ternary op does far better

Comment: Yeah I broke it down exactly to what it means. In the process I tought that surely it could be rewritten in some other way since it's basically adding a zero to a value below 10. Your solution is what I'd have done XD

Comment: Yeah this is much more simple, but @Phiter helped more to explain the construction of ternary operations

Comment: See comment in question to see how I'd do it @Phiter

Comment: oh damn that's neat XD

Answer (score 0):

You could take a function and some string methods.

```
function twoDigits(value) {
    return ('00' + value.toString()).slice(-2);
}


h1.textContent = "Time : " + twoDigits(minutes) + ":" + twoDigits(seconds);
```